# Number of simplicial polytopes with a given f-vector

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, enumerative-combinatorics, convex-polytopes, reference-request

Plenty of very nice literature is available on the characterization of f-vectors of simplicial complexes of diverse sorts (results by Billera, Bjoerner, Kalai, Stanley, among others). I mention, as an example, the Dehn-Sommerville equations, the Upper- and Lower Bound Theorems, for Simplicial Polytopes.

Are there any results on the enumeration of simplicial, convex d-polytopes with a given f-vector?

A slightly simpler question is: How does information about an f-vector (say, specifying the number of vertices, edges and triangles) determine the amount of (simplicial, convex d-) polytopes having this numbers fixed. Are there some cases where the f-vector specifies completely the polytope?

This is related to these posts:

[Number of graphs with a given number of nodes, edges and triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64810/number-of-graphs-with-a-given-number-of-nodes-edges-and-triangles)

[What is known about the number of permissible simplicial complexes given the number of k-cells?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66173/what-is-known-about-the-number-of-permissible-simplicial-complexes-given-the-numb)

And the reason I am concerned about this is that in the first of the posts, it has been commented that the problem may be way too difficult, so I was wondering whether imposing the condition that the simplicial complex be a convex polytope may *simplify* the situation a bit.

Comment: "...the condition that the simplicial complex be a convex polytope may *simplify* the situation a bit": unlikely.

Comment: I was also thinking this should bring no simplification at all, since it would be difficult to impose the (global) condition that the simplicial complex be a polytope while trying to enumerate. However, last week I heard that there are some ways to enumerate planar maps by considering a bijection to an appropriately defined set of trees, which should be easier to enumerate. See http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~jflegall/Goteborg3.pdf and http://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=Hkp4cqPR294C&oi=fnd&pg=PA1023&dq=cori+vauquelin&ots=N7eVo1TCxV&sig=LTV3GCXygktdfqUE8T_Ls_bx0pc .

Comment: I just realized this bijection is actually older. For 3-dimensional convex polytopes it's Steinitz theorem (thanks again to Joseph for the reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are just some random remarks, with one hopefully useful reference.

> "Are there some cases where the $f$-vector specifies completely the polytope?"

This is hardly what you are seeking, but for 3-polytopes, $f_2=2f_0-4$ is achieved exactly for the
$f$-vectors of simplicial polytopes.
And of course the stacked and [cyclic polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope) achieve the lower and upper bounds respectively.

I don't know if you have seen
Günter M. Ziegler's
"Convex Polytopes: Extremal Constructions and $f$-Vector Shapes"
(IAS/Park City Mathematics Series Volume 14, 2004),
which seems to directly address your questions, albeit as of several years ago.
[Here is the PDF](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/gmziegler/ftp/archiv/099utah.pdf).

Here is one tidbit.
He mentions, as a measure of our ignorance, that not even this "suspiciously innocuous
conjecture" of
Imre Bárány is settled:

> For any $d$-polytope, $f_k \ge \min \{f_0, f_{d−1}\}$.

It is (or was in 2004) only proven for $d \le 6$.

Günter has a particularly careful description of what's known about the $f$-vectors of
4-polytopes, a specialty of his.  In particular, the set of these $f$-vectors
"is *not* the set of all integral points in a polyhedral cone, or even in a
convex set."  It has concavities and holes.

Comment: The "here is the pdf" link is broken as of today. I might search for it later...

Comment: @ChristianStump: Redirected the broken PDF link.

Comment: Bárány's conjeture has now been settled, see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/167764/108884).