# Status of Barany's conjecture?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, order-theory, lattice-theory

One of Barany's most intriguing conjectures is about the $f$-vectors of convex polytopes. It asks:

> Let $P$ be a convex $d$-polytope. Is it always true that $f_k \geq \min(f_0, f_{d-1})$?

A ***convex $d$-polytope*** is the convex hull of finitely many vertices $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$. A ***face*** of the polytope is whatever you can shave off with a hyperplane. Its dimension is the dimension of the affine hull it generates. The number of faces are collected in the so-called $f$-vector $f = (f_0, \ldots, f_{d-1})$, where $f_k$ denotes the number of $k$-dimensional faces. Further information on polytopes can be found in Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes".

My question is

> What's the status of Barany's conjecture? For which classes of polytopes is it known to hold?

Here is what I know:

By double counting it is easy to see that the conjecture is true for simple and simplicial polytopes. Furthermore, it is nothing but a boring calculation to prove that the basic polytope constructions like taking products, prisms, pyramids, etc. retain the the conjectured inequality.

Given that the face lattice of a convex $d$-polytope is a graded, atomic, coatomic lattice of rank $d+2$, it makes sense to ask a far more general question: Given such a lattice, denote the number of elements of the $k$th level again by $f_k$. Is it still true that $f_k \geq \min(f_0, f_{d-1})$? Here the answer is no since I was able to construct a counterexample. But if the lattice also has what Ziegler calls the "diamond property" (every interval of length two looks like a diamond), then I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 7):

**2022 update**

Bárány's conjecture seems to have been answered in the affirmative by Joshua Hinman in a rather short paper of only 8 pages:

> - [Joshua Hinman. *"A Positive Answer to Bárány's Question on Face Numbers of Polytopes"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.02568)

Answer (score 4):

Gil Kalai lists it as open in a lecture at the
*Workshop on Convex Polytopes*, Kyoto, July 2012.
"Open Problems for Convex Polytopes I’d Love to See Solved."
[PDF slides download](http://www.gilkalai.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/kyoto-3.pdf):

---

[image: GilSlide]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This at least shows that it was still open until recently. Maybe @GilKalai can say more about the classes of polytopes for which the conjecture is true?